# How to get a value from a dynamic type variable obtained from the "value" property of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range object

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dynamic, range

I have a problem when i'm trying to obtain the values from a dynamic type variable, which is result of the "value" property of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range object. This is my scenario:

I'm using c#, and i have this values in an excel document:

```
11010001    123 0
11010002    0   23
11010003    0   120
```

When i do a copy with control+c command, i need to capture those values and make something with them, and this is the way that de Range object returns the selected values:

```
//C# Code
//Get the active and open Excel
var excel = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;

//Get the selected rows range
Range range = excel.Selection as Range;

//Get the values of selected rows
dynamic cellValue = range.Value;
```

In the cellValue variable i have the values in the following format:
[Code fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRetM.png)

So, my problem is that i don't know how to get those values by separated and insert them in my database.

Could you help me whith a suggestion or code example of how to get those values from the dynamic type variable?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

After so much trying i found the solution when i put it the dynamic variable into the watch window and right there was the way to access to the values contained, that is the following way:

```
        dynamic cellValue = range.Value;             
        int longitud = ((object[,])cellValue).Length;
        for (int i = 1; i <= longitud/3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            {
              object texto = ((object[,])cellValue)[i, j];
            }
        }
```

but note that you have to import the Microsoft.CSharp.dll and using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder; to make possible that work fine.

Regards.